# Old git-commits move to new branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, move, git-commit

**I have the following problem:**
- I have Master branch and a Dev branch and I recently added another one called TA-17.
- I submitted all my commits to this branch merged it with Dev, and closed TA-17 branch.
- Then I commited twice something to Dev branch
- Now I created a new branch (from within JIRA) called TA-38 and made the first commit to it.

**Result:**
- All old commits from TA-17 now appear as they have been made in the new TA-38 branch (and in DEV)
- No new branch is visible in the graphical display on the left next to my commits

**Expected result:**
- All old commits should still show as being submitted as TA-17 even though the branch has since be closed.
- A new branch should be visible in the graphical display on the left of my commits
- The 2 commits I submitted to DEv branch only, should not be marked as being TA-38 (63782a8 & 2a93cb3)

**After this i played around a bit more:**
- Deleted the TA-38 branch and the one commit it contained (and see all old commits now show only as being part of DEV again)
- Merged master into DEV (1 commit behind)
- Created the TA-38 branch again with 'git branch'
- Committed a new commit to TA-38 branch

and again all old commits move to the new branch (now show as part of DEV & TA-38)

**What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it ?**
https://bitbucket.org/kamaradski/t-a/commits/all

This is probably a user error, but I cannot find any information on this topic.
I might be missing something, maybe i need to rebase, or run some sort of reset...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your Bitbucket repo, I think the confusion is that `TA-38` was created off of `dev`, but `TA-38`'s merge destination is `master`. So yes, you are seeing all the commits between `TA-38` and the `master`/`dev` branch point ([5a8d807](https://bitbucket.org/kamaradski/t-a/commits/5a8d807120f6aad0caace7435429aa3e44b224f6)). This includes your old `TA-17` branch.

If you change `TA-38`'s merge destination to `dev`, the extra `TA-17` commits should not appear on the `TA-38` web page anymore. (They are still there, but as part of `dev`.)

Edit: According to [this ticket](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/9403/creating-a-branch-via-the-web-interface), permanently changing the merge destination in the web interface is an unimplemented feature. You can change it temporarily, but right now after you leave the page it will always default back to the branch defined in Bitbucket as the "main branch".

A  workaround for your problem is to set the "main branch" to `dev` instead. This can be changed in your repository settings. That may be better anyway if you use a "git-flow" style workflow where you merge your feature branches into `dev`, and then merge `dev` into `master`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't manage yet to find any information how to change the merge destination. The Bitbucket website offers a function on the webinterface, but this appears not to be saving it's setting. How would you go about doing this ?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. According to this page (https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/9403/creating-a-branch-via-the-web-interface), permanently changing the destination in the web interface is an unimplemented feature. So, you're doing everything right. It's on Bitbucket's end. I will update my answer.

Comment: You are right, changing the main branch to dev did the trick. Remaining problem however is that there is still no branch shown for TA-38. Already marked your answer as being correct, as the main problem is solved.